# In Excel VBA, How do I change the cell range that was passed as a user input to a function

Tags: excel, vba, range

I havw two columns of data which I called `XVals` and `YVals` from `A1:A65` and `B1:B65` respectively. I want to find 20% of the maximum value in `YVals` for which I use the `min` function and then after interpolation find the corresponding `Xvals` value.

The problem is that because `YVals` is a traingular function there will be two such 20% corresponding `XVals` values. I just want to select one and so I thought the best way would be to redefine the range from `A1:A65` to `"A"&MatchVal&":A65"` where `MatchVal = WorksheetFunction.Match(WorksheetFunction.Max(YVals), YVals, 1)`. But using plain ampersand characters I am not able to manipulate the range addresses.

Please suggest me a way to change this range from `A1:A65` to say `A50:A65` if `MatchVal` is 50. After this manipulation I can interpolate and get my value for `XVals` which lies on the downward slope.

Comment: do you have a sample of the vba code that you currently have?

Answer (score 1):

Declare a variable of range type and use *Set*. Something like:

```
Dim rng As Range '~~> this will hold your new range

On Error Resume Next
MatchVal = WorksheetFunction.Match(WorksheetFunction.Max(YVals), YVals, 1)
If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox "No match found.": Exit Sub
On Error Goto 0

Set rng = Range("A" & MatchVal & ":A65")
```

Take note of the *OERN* and *OEG0* lines.
I added that to make sure that your code does not error out when no match is found.
Although, you mentioned there will always be 2 matches, it pays to have possible errors checked.
You can remove it otherwise it you think it is already overkill. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

```
 =INDIRECT("A"&MatchVal&":A65")
```

The `INDIRECT()` function lets you feed in text OR dynamic values that provide text, and evaluates them as a cell ID.

Comment: Answer from L42 looks more like what you want (upvoted), but the question is not fully clear and I think this might also be helpful. I am not sure how `INDIRECT()` works with a range.

Comment: I know INDIRECT works in EXcel Worksheet but within the Excel function I was not able to make INDIRECT work...Any sugestions?